# bash script using a variable to get 7th argument

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, ubuntu

I am trying to get the 7th argument of a script through $x instead of $7, is that possible?

```
set -- $args
echo $(($x))
```

so this has to print out $7 because $x = 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Except that's not what `$((...))` does.

```
echo "${!x}"
```